# Can COALESCE be used with PERFORM/EXECUTE in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following usage of `COALESCE`, which works as expected:

```sql
[...]coalesce
(
    status_avail_direct.status,
    (   
        SELECT  status
        FROM    status_avail_direct

        WHERE   (status_avail_direct.meter_id    = oms_rec.meter) AND 
                (status_avail_direct.clt_rec_at <= clt_rec.captured_at)

        ORDER BY    status_avail_direct.clt_rec_at DESC
        LIMIT       1
    ),
    (SELECT -1)
)
```

To make it better readable, I would like to extract and document the embedded `SELECT` into some outer statement/query or alike. The important thing is that I need values of the currently processed rows for that `SELECT` to work, e.g. `oms_rec.meter` and `clt_rec.captured_at`. From my understanding, because of that a `CTE` doesn't work, but a prepared statement should exactly fit my needs. So I changed the SQL to the following:

```sql
PREPARE status_calc_by_time(timestamp with time zone, int) AS
    SELECT  status
    FROM    status_avail_direct
    
    WHERE   (status_avail_direct.meter_id    = $2) AND 
            (status_avail_direct.clt_rec_at <= $1)
    
    ORDER BY    status_avail_direct.clt_rec_at DESC
    LIMIT       1
;

[...]coalesce
(
    status_avail_direct.status,
    (EXECUTE status_calc_by_time(clt_rec.captured_at, oms_rec.meter)),
    (SELECT -1)
)
```

But that doesn't work, a syntax error is recognized instead:

> [Code: 0, SQL State: 42601]  FEHLER: Syntaxfehler bei »status_calc_by_time« Position: 263  [Script position: 1510 - 1550]

From the docs I had the feeling that wherever I can use a query directly, I might be able to use a prepared statement as well:

> statement
> Any SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or VALUES statement.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-prepare.html

> Outputs
> The command tag returned by EXECUTE is that of the prepared statement, and not EXECUTE.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-execute.html

**Is there something wrong with my syntax I don't see or does executing a prepared statement like that simply doesn't work at all in this context? In the latter case, where can I use EXECUTE most likely/only?**

Comment: *I have the following usage of COALESCE* This is not SQL query. Convert it. Use `SELECT COALESCE((subquery1), (subquery2))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXECUTE` is a PL/pgSQL statement, not an SQL statement, so you cannot use it as subquery inside an SQL statement.

You could write a function `status_calc_by_time`, then your code would work if you simply remove the `EXECUTE`.

If you write the function in `LANGUAGE sql` and make it `VOLATILE`, it might get inlined by the database, so you have no performance loss at all.

Comment: `oms_rec.meter` and `clt_rec.captured_at` are only available in the outer `SELECT`, consequently trying a CTE fails for me. My sub select is pretty much a function call with 2 values of the result set as arguments. Are you sure this should work with a CTE? I can't seem to reference the required "arguments".

Comment: Sorry, that must have been a brain fart. Edited with a better idea.